# Incorrect sequence of Carousel elements in Facebook Messenger Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-messages

I am trying to send **horizontally scrollable carousel** message on Facebook workplace platform using the generic template as described in the messenger platform documentation(Ref: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/template/generic)

The template that I am using looking something like this:

```
[
  {
    "text": "Hi!!!!"
  },
  {
    "attachment": {
      "type": "template",
      "payload": {
        "template_type": "generic",
        "elements": [
          {
            "title": "Some Title 1",
            "image_url": "some image url",
            "buttons": [
              {
                "title": "button_title1",
                "type": "postback",
                "payload": "Title 1"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "title": "Some Title 2",
            "image_url": "some image url",
            "buttons": [
              {
                "title": "button_title2",
                "type": "postback",
                "payload": "Title 2"
              }
            ]
          },{
            "title": "Some Title 3",
            "image_url": "some image url",
            "buttons": [
              {
                "title": "button_title3",
                "type": "postback",
                "payload": "Title 3"
              }
            ]
          },

        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Everything worked as I expected but, from the past 2 weeks or so, the **order of carousel elements(cards in my case)** isn't what I am expecting(i.e., Title1, Title2, Title3). The elements in the carousel are shown in a different order every time I use it. I just want to know if anyone else has the same issue or it has something to do with my code?

The code that I have used to send the message in the end is:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //(async ref:https://www.npmjs.com/package/async)
    async.eachSeries(

            //facebookMessages is the message template that I am using(posted above)
            facebookMessages,
            (msg, callback) => {

            //sendFBSenderAction sends the message to FB using api(https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>)
            this.sendFBSenderAction(sender, 'typing_on')
            .then(() => this.sleep(this.messagesDelay))
            .then(() => {
                facebookMessages.attachment ? this.sendFbAttachment(msg) : this.sendFBMessage(sender, msg);
                facebookMessages.attachment = false;
            })
            .then(() => callback())
            .catch(callback);
        },
        err => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                reject(err);
            } else {
                console.log('Messages sent');
                resolve();
            }
        }
);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there’s already a current bug report for this - https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/260229951577494/

Subscribe to that, to be updated when the status of that bug report changes.